# Where is my .emacs file on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, emacs

so i am trying to add the google go module to my .emacs file so that when I use emacs to edit my .go file it will have the appropriate indentations and highlight of the words. Ive looked online and it seems that I need to add the following code snippets to my .emacs file (which i cannot find!)

```lisp
;; go mode
(setq load-path (cons "/usr/local/go/misc/emacs" load-path))
(require 'go-mode-load)
```

I have put go-mode-load.el and go-mode.el in my .emacs.d/ directory I believe i still need to find the .emacs file to add the code listed above I am running OS X if this helps. Can someone help me get this working thank you!

Comment: should be in ~/  if it isn't there, you should just be able to create it?

Answer (score 23):

Eval this with `M-:` `(find-file user-init-file)`

Emacs will then open what it considers your user initialization file.

I have

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") (lambda () (interactive) (find-file-other-window user-init-file)))
```

in my `.emacs` so that i can easily edit this.

Comment: To be a little more specific, run `emacs`, hit `M-` (`ESC`) to go to the scratch buffer, enter `(find-file user-init-file)` and hit `C-J` to evaluate and open the active initialization file.

Answer (score 17):

The Emacs manual tells you:

```
This file, if it exists, specifies how to initialize Emacs for you.
Emacs looks for your init file using the filenames `~/.emacs', `~/.emacs.el',
or `~/.emacs.d/init.el'; you can choose to use any one of these three
names.  Here, `~/' stands for your home directory.
```

Most people use `~/.emacs`, I think.  Just do `C-x C-f ~/.emacs` to create it if you do not yet have one.

Comment: I would recommend `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, though, because that makes it easier to keep the whole Emacs configuration under version control.

Comment: @lunaryorn I seem to have auto generated a ~/.emacs.d directory but there is nothing in it than some empty directory called "auto-save-list". When I find my "user-init-file" emacs tells me it's "~/.emacs", but this file doesn't exist, only the .emacs.d directory does. So if I just add an init.el file within .emacs.d how would the emacs application know what to read when it thinks the user-init-file is ~/.emacs?