# Where to update `load-path`? What file do I put the update code in?

Tags: emacs

I am new to emacs and could you tell me where to find the load-path. because i get the answer below to include javascript library in to emacs
In short where am going to type "(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/user/emacsfiles")"

"Download moz.el and place it in Emacs’ load-path. Alternatively, place it in any directory (e.g. “/home/user/emacsfiles”) then add that directory to the load-path, as follows:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/user/emacsfiles")
```

Comment: See also related questions, [for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966380/where-is-the-emacs-file-in-windows-gnu-emacs), [another one for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows), and [for Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524627/where-is-my-emacs-file-on-mac-os-x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This refers to your Emacs [init file](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html). From the Emacs manual:

> When Emacs is started, it normally tries to load a Lisp program from
>   an initialization file, or init file for short. This file, if it
>   exists, specifies how to initialize Emacs for you. Emacs looks for
>   your init file using the filenames ~/.emacs, ~/.emacs.el, or
>   ~/.emacs.d/init.el; you can choose to use any one of these three names
>   (see Find Init). Here, ~/ stands for your home directory.

Don't worry too much about the mention of "a Lisp program" in the quote above: the init file is just a simple text file. Just open it with any editor (e.g. Emacs) and append the `(add-to-list ...)` line at the end. Then save it, close Emacs, and open a new one -- if you provide the correct path, the error message should have disappeared.

Comment: thank you..and from where can i access the init file.i.e where is it found?

Comment: That's actually written in the above quote from the manual. You have three options, use either `~/.emacs`, `~/.emacs.el`, or `~/emacs.d/init.el`. Here, the `~` character refers to your home directory. If you type `C-x C-f` followed by any of these three paths, Emacs will happily locate and open that file for you.
If you want to go through the trouble of clicking on the link in my answer, you'll get taken straight to the above quote, including the part where it says "(see Find Init)". That's where you get information about finding your init file.

Comment: No worries. If this solved your problem, please consider marking my answer as correct and/or upvote it for the benefit of others who might run into the same problem in the future.